# How to set focusto do it after the text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the focus is on the text and how to do it after the text?

```
 <TextField
                    classes={{
                        root: cl.notesInputRoot
                    }}
                    multiline
                    autoFocus={true}
                    //inputRef={textInput}
                    rows={4}
                    value='te'
                    className={cl.notesInput}
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={handleChangeNote}

                />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Input.setSelectionRange, part of [the Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) for interacting with text selections and the text cursor: